# Is there any way I can allow a generic function to use specialized functions?

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Magic<T> {
    phantom: PhantomData<T>,
}

struct A;
struct B;

impl Magic<A> {
    fn value() -> i32 {
        5
    }
}

impl Magic<B> {
    fn value() -> i32 {
        10
    }
}

impl<T> Magic<T> {
    fn extra() -> i32 {
        Magic::<T>::value() + 5
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

It fails:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `value` found for type `Magic<T>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:25:9
   |
3  | struct Magic<T> {
   | --------------- function or associated item `value` not found for this
...
25 |         Magic::<T>::value() + 5
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `Magic<T>`
```

This makes sense because `T` isn't necessarily `A` or `B`. However, when I call this function, I am confident that it will always be either `A` or `B`.

Knowing this, is there any way I can allow this generic function to use these specialized functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this has nothing to do with the programming / Rust concept of *specialization*, which usually means having a *more specific* implementation of a trait in certain cases for performance or when multiple implementations may be valid.

---

Go back and re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/), specifically the the chapter ["Traits: Defining Shared Behavior"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-02-traits.html).

Common functionality is expressed through traits; introduce one and use it and the *compiler* asserts that any type you use can do what you need. There's no need to rely on the extremely fallible "I am confident".

```
trait Value {
    fn value() -> i32;
}

impl Value for Magic<A> {
    fn value() -> i32 {
        5
    }
}

impl Value for Magic<B> {
    fn value() -> i32 {
        10
    }
}

impl<T> Magic<T>
where
    Self: Value,
{
    fn extra() -> i32 {
        Magic::<T>::value() + 5
    }
}
```